# SIGILL after fork in Sage/Python

Tags: python, crash, fork, sage, libdispatch

I'm doing some calculations with [Sage](http://sagemath.org).
I am playing around with `fork`. I have a very simple test case which is basically like this:

```
def fork_test():
    import os
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid != 0:
        print "parent, child: %i" % pid
        os.waitpid(pid, 0)
    else:
        print "child"
        try:
            # some dummy matrix calculation
        finally:
            os._exit(0)
```

(Look below for `_fork_test_func()` for some matrix calculations.)

And I'm getting:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Unhandled SIGILL: An illegal instruction occurred in Sage.
This probably occurred because a *compiled* component of Sage has a bug
in it and is not properly wrapped with sig_on(), sig_off(). You might
want to run Sage under gdb with 'sage -gdb' to debug this.
Sage will now terminate.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

With this (incomplete) backtrace:

```
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
BUG IN LIBDISPATCH: flawed group/semaphore logic

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c6d1d46 __kill + 10
1   libcsage.dylib                  0x0000000101717f33 sigdie + 124
2   libcsage.dylib                  0x0000000101717719 sage_signal_handler + 364
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86b1094a _sigtramp + 26
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff89a66c74 _dispatch_thread_semaphore_signal + 27
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff89a66f3e _dispatch_apply2 + 143
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff89a66e30 dispatch_apply_f + 440
7   libBLAS.dylib                   0x00007fff906ca435 APL_dtrsm + 1963
8   libBLAS.dylib                   0x00007fff906702b6 cblas_dtrsm + 882
9   matrix_modn_dense_double.so     0x0000000108612615 void FFLAS::Protected::ftrsmRightLowerNoTransUnit<double>::delayed<FFPACK::Modular<double> >(FFPACK::Modular<double> const&, unsigned long, unsigned long, FFPACK::Modular<double>::Element*, unsigned long, FFPACK::Modular<double>::Element*, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long) + 2853
10  matrix_modn_dense_double.so     0x0000000108611daa void FFLAS::Protected::ftrsmRightLowerNoTransUnit<double>::delayed<FFPACK::Modular<double> >(FFPACK::Modular<double> const&, unsigned long, unsigned long, FFPACK::Modular<double>::Element*, unsigned long, FFPACK::Modular<double>::Element*, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long) + 698
11  matrix_modn_dense_double.so     0x0000000108612ccf void FFLAS::Protected::ftrsmRightLowerNoTransUnit<double>::operator()<FFPACK::Modular<double> >(FFPACK::Modular<double> const&, unsigned long, unsigned long, FFPACK::Modular<double>::Element*, unsigned long, FFPACK::Modular<double>::Element*, unsigned long) + 831
12  ???                             0x00007f99e481a028 0 + 140298940424232

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c6d26d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86b24f4c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86b24d13 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86b0f1d1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c6d26d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86b24f4c _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86b24d13 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86b0f1d1 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00007fff5ec8e418  rcx: 0x00007fff5ec8df28  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x000000000000b8f7  rsi: 0x0000000000000004  rbp: 0x00007fff5ec8df40  rsp: 0x00007fff5ec8df28
   r8: 0x00007fff5ec8e418   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x000000000000000a  r11: 0x0000000000000202
  r12: 0x00007f99ea500de0  r13: 0x0000000000000003  r14: 0x00007fff5ec8e860  r15: 0x00007fff906ca447
  rip: 0x00007fff8c6d1d46  rfl: 0x0000000000000202  cr2: 0x00007fff74a29848
Logical CPU: 0
```

Is there something special I need to do after a `fork`? I looked up the `fork` decorator of Sage and it looks like it basically does the same.

The crash also happens with the `fork` decorator of Sage itself. Another test case:

```
def fork_test2():
    def test():
        # do some stuff
    from sage.parallel.decorate import fork
    test_ = fork(test, verbose=True)
    test_()
```

---

Even simpler test case:

```
def _fork_test_func():
    while True:
        m = matrix(QQ, 100, [randrange(-100,100) for i in range(100*100)])
        m.right_kernel()

def fork_test():
    import os
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid != 0:
        print "parent, child: %i" % pid
        os.waitpid(pid, 0)
    else:
        print "child"
        try:
            _fork_test_func()
        finally:
            os._exit(0)
```

Results in a slightly different crash:

```
python(48672) malloc: *** error for object 0x11185f000: pointer being freed already on death-row
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

With backtrace:

```
Crashed Thread:  1  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
*** error for object 0x11185f000: pointer being freed already on death-row


Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   matrix2.so                      0x0000000107fa403f __pyx_pw_4sage_6matrix_7matrix2_6Matrix_71right_kernel_matrix + 27551
1   ???                             0x000000000000000d 0 + 13

Thread 1 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c6d239a __semwait_signal_nocancel + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86b17e1b nanosleep$NOCANCEL + 138
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86b7b9a8 usleep$NOCANCEL + 54
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86b67eca __abort + 203
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86b67dff abort + 192
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86b43905 szone_error + 580
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86b43f7d free_large + 229
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86b3b8f8 free + 199
8   libBLAS.dylib                   0x00007fff906b0431 __APL_dgemm_block_invoke_0 + 132
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff89a65f01 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff89a620b6 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff89a631fa _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 304
12  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86b24d0b _pthread_wqthread + 404
13  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86b0f1d1 start_wqthread + 13
```

The same happens also for this:

```
def fork_test2():
    from sage.parallel.decorate import fork
    test_ = fork(_fork_test_func, verbose=True)
    test_()
```

-- but only if you used some other matrix calculations before.

---

This test case also works on a fresh Sage session:

```
def _fork_test_func(iterator=None):
    if not iterator:
        import itertools
        iterator = itertools.count()
    for i in iterator:
        m = matrix(QQ, 100, [randrange(-100,100) for i in range(100*100)])
        m.right_kernel()

def fork_test():
    _fork_test_func(range(10))
    import os
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid != 0:
        print "parent, child: %i" % pid
        os.waitpid(pid, 0)
    else:
        print "child"
        try:
            _fork_test_func()
        finally:
            os._exit(0)
```

---

I have downloaded the binaries for MacOSX 64bit of Sage 5.8.

(Note that I also asked on ask.sagemath.org [here](http://ask.sagemath.org/question/2627/sigill-in-forked-process).)

Answer (score 1):

Both of these crashreports indicate that a multi-threaded process `fork()`ed, which greatly restricts the set of operations that are safe to execute in the child, essentially you can only call `execve()` et al, along with a few other functions from the list of [async-signal-safe](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03) functions

This is documented in the CAVEATS section of the `fork(2)` manpage as well as in the [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html):

> A process shall be created with a single thread. If a multi-threaded process calls fork(), the new process shall contain a replica of the calling thread and its entire address space, possibly including the states of mutexes and other resources. Consequently, to avoid errors, the child process may only execute async-signal-safe operations until such time as one of the exec functions is called.

Since many APIs in Mac OS X frameworks will cause the process to become multithreaded, if you want the fork-child to be fully useable, you must limit you operations in the parent process before `fork` to APIs documented not to make a process multithreaded (essentially only POSIX APIs).

Comment: Hm, well, Sage and Python is supposed to be able to support `fork`. If it isn't, it needs some bugfixing somewhere. I am searching for where it goes wrong. And I'm searching for either a workaround or a fix. Also, Sage and Python shouldn't use any MacOSX APIs.

Comment: Both backtraces show a frame in libBLAS, that is definitely not a library that is safe to use after fork of a multithreaded process.

Comment: So what would be needed to make it safe? (Note that I really want to make it possible. Sage is supposed to support that.)

Comment: As mentioned above, don't call anything that makes the process multithreaded before `fork()`. Or re-exec yourself after `fork()` to sidestep the whole issue.

Comment: Both are not options for me and I still need to make the forked process work. How can I patch libBLAS? Or libdispatch?

Comment: there is no way to do that, these are not supported after `fork` of a multithreaded process and there is no way to "patch" them to make it so (note that in the second crashreport, you ran into the fact that `malloc` doesn't work correctly after `fork` of a multithreaded process, there is no way to patch out the use of `malloc`...)

Comment: I still don't really see why exactly it does not work and why it is impossible to make it work. I'm quite sure I can develop a version of `malloc`/`free` which works in a forked process.